# Rails, Can not get a value throug a HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models with a HABTM relation like:

`font.rb` with

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :personas
```

and `persona.rb`

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :fonts
```

I try to get all the fonts linked to a specific persona with

```
    Font.includes(:personas).where(persona: persona)
```

But I get an error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: fonts.persona`

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Font.includes(:personas).where("personas.id": persona.id)
```

or simpler:

```
persona.fonts
```

Comment: `persona.fonts` I think i tried everything but this! Thanks!